# How to push AWS ECS Fargate cloudwatch logs to UI for users to see their long running task real time logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am creating an app where the long running tasks are getting executed in ECS Fargate and logs are getting pushed to CloudWatch. Now, am looking for a way to give the users an ability in the UI to see those realtime live logs while their tasks are running.

I am thinking of the below approach..

1. Saving logs temporarily in DynamoDB
2. DynamoDB stream with batch will trigger a lambda.
3. Lambda will trigger an AWS Appsync mutation with None data source.
4. In UI client will subscribed to that mutation to get real time updates. (depends on the batch size, example 5 batch means 5 logs lines )

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/appsync-notify-subscribers-real-time/

Is there any other techniques or methods that i can think of?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Cloudwatch default save in S3 bucket ability and add SNS to let clients choose which topic they want to trail the log. Removing extra DynamoDB.

[image: Possible Architecture]

Comment: Can you explain Cloudwatch default save in S3 bucket ability? Do you mean export ?Not sure if that can done automatically in real time!

Comment: ok, s3 can be also an extra service, you could directly send cloudwatch logs events to UI. [CloudWatch logs events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html), but it will not store in s3 or client-side kinda rate-limiting won't be there.

Comment: I think thats what my question is?  how are you sending the events directly to UI. Unless you are using some other service like appsync  to push the data to a web socket and clients subscribed to it.